# mapping several layers of nested data in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I can't figure out how my first and second layers are mapping correctly, but my third layer is giving me an error. Can I borrow a fresh set of eyes? What am I doing wrong?

Here is a sample of my data (json)

```
exports.LicenseItems = [
    { 
        id: 100, 
        network_name: "scala", 
        licenseProperties: [
            { id: 101, name: "Item 1: ", value: " Value 1" },
            { id: 102, name: "Item 2 ", value: " Value 2" },
            { id: 103, name: "Item 3 ", value: " Value 3" },
            { 
                id: 104, 
                name: "Item 4", 
                Licenses: [
                    {id: 1041, name: "SubItem 4.1", value: " SubValue 1"},
                    {id: 1042, name: "SubItem 4.2", value: " SubValue 2"},
                    {id: 1043, name: "SubItem 4.3", value: " SubValue 3"},
                ],
            },
            { 
                id: 105, 
                name: "Item 5", 
                Licenses: [
                    {id: 1051, name: "SubItem 5.1", value: " SubValue 1"},
                    {id: 1052, name: "SubItem 5.2", value: " SubValue 1"},
                    {id: 1053, name: "SubItem 5.3", value: " SubValue 1"},
                ],
            },
            { id: 106, name: "Item 6", value: " Value 6" },
            { id: 107, name: "Item 7", value: " Value 7" },
            { id: 108, name: "Item 8", value: " Value 8" },
        ],
    },
    {...},
    {...},
];
```

Here is my mapping script in ReactJS

```
{LicenseItems.map((item, index) => (
    <Grid item xs={12} style={{padding: 0}} key={index}>
        <ListItem 
            divider 
            button
            onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <ListItemText primary={<CMLabel>{item.network_name}</CMLabel>}/>
            <IconButton>
                <Icon>{this.state.open ? 'expand_more' : 'expand_less'}</Icon>
            </IconButton>
        </ListItem> 
        <Collapse
            in={!this.state.open} 
            timeout="auto" 
            unmountOnExit
            className={classes.submenu}>
            <List component="div" disablePadding>
                {item.licenseProperties.map((properties, propertyIndex) => (
                    <ListItem key={propertyIndex}>
                        <ListItemText
                            primary={
                                <span>
                                    <CMLabel>{properties.name}</CMLabel> {properties.value}
                                    <div className={classes.subdueList}>
                                        {properties.Licenses.map((row, featuredIndex) => (
                                            <span key={featuredIndex}>
                                                <CMLabel>{row.name}</CMLabel> {row.value}
                                            </span>
                                        ))}
                                    </div>
                                </span>
                            } 
                        />
                    </ListItem> 
                ))}
            </List>
        </Collapse> 
    </Grid>
))}
```

My output is rendering the first level (LicenseItems) and the second level (licenseProperties). But the thrid mapping level (Licenses), is not rendering and giving me this error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

See the image for some visual help

[image]

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: I think not all the nodes have "Licenses" under "licenseProperties" list. You should have guard condition in the code to ensure if it does have then only call map on it... that's guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, at this line:

```
{properties.Licenses.map((row, featuredIndex)
```

in some of your data, the properties object doesn't have a `Licenses`field and hence you're getting this error.

You can check if it exists before mapping first, like

```
<div className={classes.subdueList}>
  {properties.Licenses!=null ? properties.Licenses.map((row, featuredIndex) => (
    <span key={featuredIndex}>
      <CMLabel>{row.name}</CMLabel> {row.value}
    </span>
  )):<div/>}
</div>
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver! Thanks a lot my friend.